# Text in place of Finder icons (MacOS Sierra)

Tags: finder, macos

My finder looks like this:

[image: Finder]

If I click on the text 'view', 'action' etc, it shows all the options and I'm able to use it quite normally. What gives?

How do I get the icons + buttons back?

Comment: Is your issue the fact that there is text instead of icons? It isn't too clear what you're asking here…

Comment: @Jackson1442 I guess I forgot to ask the main question! Have updated it, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting the buttons back is actually really simple:

First, select **View > Customize Toolbar...** in the menu bar.

[image]

Now, just make sure the dropdown (the one outlined in red) has the option you want selected. The default is Icon Only.